# Difference between Collection.toArray() and Collection.toArray(Object obj[])

Tags: java, arrays

According to java doc for toArray() 
Returns an array containing all of the elements in this collection.

and toArray(Object obj[]).
Returns an array containing all of the elements in this collection; the runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array.

first toArray() i understand but second toArray(Object obj[]) i can't understand.Please explain with example.

Comment: The [extended Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray()) for `toArray(T[])` explains it rather nicely, in my opinion...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One is generic, the other isn't. `toArray()` will return `Object[]` while `toArray(T[])` will return an array of type `T[]`.

Sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] baseArray = new ArrayList<String>().toArray();
    System.out.println(baseArray.getClass().getCanonicalName());

    String[] improvArray = new ArrayList<String>().toArray(new String[5]);
    System.out.println(improvArray.getClass().getCanonicalName());
}
```

Output:

```
java.lang.Object[]
java.lang.String[]
```

Comment: Thanks Jeroen,can u explain with example?

Comment: I have edited my post with an example. By using the overloaded version with a generic parameter, you can specify the type of the resulting array. This will allow you to use a specific type instead of `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the second method is `toArray(T[] a)` instead of `toArray(Object[] a)`. The `T` in the first function header is called a *type parameter*, which means that the actual class it is referring to changes depending on how you call the method. The type parameter can be used by the `toArray` method to do things using the type `T`, without knowing what `T` actually is.

In this example, `T` would be `String`:

```
x.toArray(new String[0])
```

In this example, `T` would be `Integer`:

```
x.toArray(new Integer[0])
```

In this example, `T` would be `MyClass`:

```
x.toArray(new MyClass[0])
```

The method `toArray(T[] a)` uses the provided type information to return an array of the given type. For example, the first example would return an array of type `String`, while the second example would return an array of type `Integer`.

As a result, a call to `toArray()` produces the same result (An array of `Object`) as a call to `toArray(new Object[0])`.

For more information on generics, you can have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/04/java-generics-quick-tutorial.html).